# Amp issue with buckboost plus usbc decoy setup

Tags: power, polarity

First I would like to say that I am a software developer with limited skills in electronics.

I am trying to build a setup to charge my electric longboard batteries from an usbc power delivery input. I have an usbc decoy connected to a buckboost module, which enables me to set to output voltage and amperage.

Now, my target is to have 28.6v and around 1.2a as an output.
The problem is that I can't seem to be able to set the current. From what I understand it needs to be under load to be set, but when I connect the battery the buckboost restarts, I presume some protection kicks in. So I can never see the current of the setup... I just blindly turn the amp knob with no feedback.

I checked the polarity for my setup compared with the originAl charger (see pictures) and seems to be the same.
Any suggestion is highly appreciated!
Thanks for reading.
[image: input]
[image: output]
[image: my polarity]
[image: original charger polarity]

Comment: Schematics and data sheets needed. What amp are you talking about? Do you mean to say "current" when you say "amp" maybe?

Comment: Yes, I mean current. The input should be 3a,and the output I need is 1.2a. There is no schematic, its just a decoy connected to the buckboost.

Comment: Are you measuring with a load. No load, no current.

Comment: well i was thinking that is the issue. However i can't use the real consumer (the battery i want to charge), as it is restarting the buckboost.What can i use as a consumer ?

Answer (score 0):

So in the end what i had to do is to really turn the current knob down for quite a while, and then i was able to plug in my battery/consumer and slowly raise the current until i got what i needed. Previously was at a too high level and it was triggering the protection on the battery.